# Reordering column nodes in heatmap.3 while maintaining dendrogram

Tags: heatmap, dendrogram

[image]

I've generated this heatmap using heatmap.3. Clustering is performed based on the dendrogram, but for presentation purposed, I'd like to re-order the nodes such that dark blue is left and dark red is right while maintaining the dendrogram. I've read about re-order:
newdendro<-reorder(as.dendrogram(myclust(mydist(heatdata.scaled))),10:1,agglo.FUN=colSums)

But colSums(heatdata.scaled) is not stored in the dendrogram. How do I 
1) use colSums(heatdata.scaled) to reorder the nodes
2) call this updated dendrogram in heatmap.3?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is missing a self contained reproducible example. So I will use the `mtcars` data. And since I'm now working on the [heatmaply](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/heatmaply/index.html) package, I'll give an answer using it (but you can just change heatmaply to your desired function, and the code will work the same).

```
# get data
x <- mtcars
# row dend:
hc_r <- as.dendrogram(hclust(dist(x)))
# col dend:
hc_c <- as.dendrogram(hclust(dist(t(x))))

# weights and reordering
wts_r <- rowSums(x)
wts_c <- colSums(x) # apply(x, 2, mean)

hc_r <- rev(reorder(hc_r,wts_r))
hc_c <- reorder(hc_c,wts_c)

x2 <- x[order.dendrogram(hc_r), 
        order.dendrogram(hc_c)]

# plot
library(heatmaply)
heatmaply(x2, dendrogram = "none")
```

And we get the following beautiful (and interactive) plot:

[image]